# How do I make subplots with this method

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a subplot of histograms for each of the features in the dataset.

The following code is what I have already tried to fix the problem. Consider train dataset, which has 9 columns and which I want to be plotted in a 3*3 subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)

i=0
for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        train.iloc[:,i].hist()
        i=i+1
```

I'm getting all histograms in the last subplot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I found this method with which I was able to get what I was looking for  :      train.plot(kind='box',subplots=True, layout=(3,3),sharex=False,sharey=False)

Answer (score 0):

here my suggestion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

for i in range(1,7):
  # Cut your figure into 3 row and 3 columns
  # and create the plot in the i subplot.
  # here I used the f-string formatting that is available from python3.6
  plt.subplot(f'33{i}')
  plt.hist(random.randrange(0, 10))
```

you can find more ideas at this amazing website: [The Python Graph Gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.DataFrame.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) can take an `ax` parameter which is the Matplotlib axes to use.